# Why are the positive bonus rep red in the reputation tab?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, reputation

I noticed that (un)accepts...

[image]

...and bounties...

[image]

are red there. Why are all the rep received from bonuses RED?!

I understand unaccepts - they give negative rep gain and therefore logically made red (on any SE site).

But why do accepts have a red background? It should be green, that's the wonderful color which is used for accepts everywhere on SE. Also bounties: why red again? Why not blue, the known color of bounties?

Comment: Blue for bounties and bounties awarded is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Red, or #ab2020, is the accent colour used throughout this site for highlighting.

- .review-indicator span
- h3 a:hover
- .bounty-indicator
- .bounty-indicator-tab
- .bounty-award
- .bounty-vote-off

Ask Different isn't the only site to use red (or a shade of red) for this.
For example, [Arqade uses red for bounties](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) and Webmasters uses orange (these were just the first two graduated sites I tried).